# Apache log files getting too big, how do I make it save on a per-day basis

Tags: apache-2.2

Apache combined log files are getting too large each day in a single file, it is hitting over hundreds megabytes,

Which is a quick way or how can I configure to store files per day basis?

Will this work?

```
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs -l /var/log/httpd/access.log.%Y-%m-%d 2419200"
```

operating on Linux.

Comment: Which operating system are you using ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use rotatelogs

```
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs PATH_TO_LOG_DIR/access_log.%Y%m%d 86400 -360" common
```

Comment: this should be put into your vhost file in sites-enabled of your apache config dir

Comment: That's rotatelogs, not logrotate.  logrotate is usually run from a cron job and rotates existing logs.  The config directory is `/etc/logrotate.d/`.

Answer (score 3):

As you are using linux, you can use the [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate). Something like this which is lifted from an Ubuntu system I have handy but note you'll probably need to modify it for other distributions.

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 7
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 640 root adm
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                if [ -f "`. /etc/apache2/envvars ; echo ${APACHE_PID_FILE:-/var/run/apache2.pid}`" ]; then
                        /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null
                fi
        endscript
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Linux then **logrotate**. Or you can log to a remote server directly for example with syslog-ng.

Comment: You can also use rsyslog instead of syslog-ng.